# Divide the width between the table elements evenly

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I am trying to make a table to display something like this:

```
 ________
|__|__|__|
|__|__|__|
```

All boxes need to be split evenly, and the middle box in the bottom row will have a very large image that will be forced into a smaller size. This is my current XML layout, but I wind up with a layout like this:

```
 ________
|_|____|_|
|_|____|_|
```

---

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:stretchColumns="1">

    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Unused"
            android:padding="3dip" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Top Center"
            android:padding="3dip" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_column="3"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Unused"
            android:padding="3dip" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="----&gt;" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/mainImg"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
        />
        <TextView
            android:layout_column="3"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="&lt;----" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m not sure what you’re doing wrong.  I tried a table layout like yours in the past and could not get it to work properly.  I’ve found accomplishing a layout like yours to be easier using a relative layout.

You set the left box to left_align, the right box to right_align, etc.  Then give them all a dip value to correspond with the size screen you are currently using and they will update correctly across other screen sizes.

Unfortunately, once you get beyond 3 in a row (say 4 or 5 boxes), this fix no longer works.

Edit:
As per Mal's comment it appears an alternative is to use a relative layout with his XML code.

I will post my original fix for reference.  I also neglected to mention this is actually a relative layout inside a frame layout.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >  

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/start"
            android:layout_width="110dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="@string/title_start" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/options"
        android:layout_width="110dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="@string/title_options" />   

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/scores"
        android:layout_width="110dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="@string/title_scores" />  

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I switched from table layout to relative and it worked, but this answer isn't totally correct.

Answer (score 5):

You have to use linear layouts with weights.

Try this out, you may have to add some more stuff, but it should get you started.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
            <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
            <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        </LinearLayout>    
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
            <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
            <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This can work, but is subject to very poor performance. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/9431087/1594913

Answer (score 0):

Try android:layout_weight="1" in your button/child elements of RowLayout

[image]

```
     <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/str1"  
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button10"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/str2"  
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button11"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/str3"  
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button12"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/strMinus"  
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

    </TableRow>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** Android Percent Support Library helps us to divide evenly any android widgets using its percentage attribute.

> [Code and Concept](http://code2concept.blogspot.in/2015/08/android-percent-support-lib-sample.html)
>
> [Github Demo](https://github.com/nitiwari-dev/android-percent-layout-sample)

```
<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fifty_huntv"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#ff7acfff"
        android:text="20% - 50%"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_heightPercent="20%"
        app:layout_widthPercent="50%" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/fifty_huntv"
        android:background="#ffff5566"
        android:text="80%-50%"
        app:layout_heightPercent="80%"
        app:layout_widthPercent="50%"
        />

</android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```

Really Awesome.