# Layout Weight warning Nested weight bad performance

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I am new to android. Now i get warning for Nested weight bad performance.I have only one image and three buttons in my first screen. PLs give me some idea.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/backgroundColor"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:weightSum="10"
    >


    <ImageView
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:id="@+id/imageLogo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:contentDescription="@string/Img"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/home_screen_logo" />

    <LinearLayout
       android:layout_weight="6"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip" 
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        >

        <LinearLayout android:layout_height="0dp" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/temp"></LinearLayout>
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/login"
        android:contentDescription="@string/Img"  
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
    <LinearLayout android:layout_height="0dp" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"></LinearLayout>
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnFbLogin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
         android:background="@drawable/btnfb"
         android:contentDescription="@string/Img"
        />
    <LinearLayout android:layout_height="0dp" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"></LinearLayout>
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnRegister"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/btnregister"
        android:contentDescription="@string/Img"/>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Nested weights are bad for performance because:
>
> > Layout weights require a widget to be measured twice. When a LinearLayout with non-zero weights is nested inside another LinearLayout with non-zero weights, then the number of measurements increase exponentially.
>
> It's always better to use `RelativeLayouts` and adjust your view according to the places of other views without using specific dpi values.

courtesy: [Why are nested weights bad for performance? Alternatives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9430764/why-are-nested-weights-bad-for-performance-alternatives)

Comment: Why is this down-voted? I need a reason.

Answer (score 0):

Nested weights are bad for performance because:

> Layout weights require a widget to be measured twice. When a
>   LinearLayout with non-zero weights is nested inside another
>   LinearLayout with non-zero weights, then the number of measurements
>   increase exponentially.

It's always better to use [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-relativelayout.html)s and adjust your view according to the places of other views without using specific dpi values.

Refer: http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-efficiency.html

You can use a RelativeLayout in most cases to avoid such expensive measurements. In a RelativeLayout, views are aligned with their parent, with the RelativeLayout itself, or with other views.

To clearly understand how the views are positioned with respect to each other, a wireframe of the layout can be captured by using HierarchyViewer perspective of Android SDK.

Comment: Link is broken :(

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `android:weightSum="10"` from the linear layout, also remove `android:layout_weight="1"`

Now you see that the warning has disappeared!

Make sure to **keep** the weights in the buttons and other stuff in linear layouts!

I hope that this may solve your problem :)