# Using a RelativeLayout to vertically split two fragments evenly

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-relativelayout

I am trying to create a simple layout with three fragments. On the left, I want two fragments over eachother, each taking 50% of the height of the screen. On the right, I want one large container fragment, like this:

```
+-----+-----------------+
| f1  | detail_container|
|     |                 |
+-----+                 |
| f2  |                 |
|     |                 |
+-----+-----------------+
```

I got it working with two `LinearLayouts`, using `layout_height="0dp"` and `layout_weight="1"`, but I got the message it is bad for performance, so I set out to use a `RelativeLayout`. What I have now is this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:divider="?android:attr/dividerHorizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:showDividers="middle"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragment1"
            android:name="com.example.Fragment1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height=""
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            tools:layout="@android:layout/list_content" />

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragment2"
            android:name="com.example.Fragment2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height=""
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            tools:layout="@android:layout/list_content" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/action_detail_container"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I don't know how to fill in the `layout_height` value of the two fragments. I tried all kinds of values, but they seem all to have to be absolute (which I don't want).

Comment: add a `View` with `android:layout_height="0dip"` and `android:layout_centerVertical="true`, then align one of them above it and one below it using `android:layout_above="<id>"` and `android:layout_above="<id>"`.

Comment: @hypd09 How would I define them to fill the remaining space? Also, it feels a little hackish.

Comment: just set `android:layout_height="match_parent"`. `RelativeLayout` is used by setting relations, nothing hacky about that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is my solution with a common workaround to avoid nested weight :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
              android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
              android:baselineAligned="false"
              android:divider="?android:attr/dividerHorizontal"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:showDividers="middle"
              tools:context=".MainActivity" >
    <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

        <View android:id="@+id/dummyView"
              android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:layout_height="0dp"
              android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
        <fragment
                android:id="@+id/fragment1"
                android:name="com.example.Fragment1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_alignTop="@id/dummyView"
                tools:layout="@android:layout/list_content" />

        <fragment
                android:id="@+id/fragment2"
                android:name="com.example.Fragment2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@id/dummyView"
                tools:layout="@android:layout/list_content" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/action_detail_container"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="3" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not switch it around, i.e. use a `RelativeLayout` as your root view, and a vertical `LinearLayout` as a container for the fragments? Just use `alignParentLeft` on the container and `toRightOf` on the `FrameLayout`.

Comment: Would I be able to have the two smaller fragments at 1/3 of the width and the large one at 2/3?

Comment: Oh, I didn't know you wanted such proportions... In this case, @Andros' solution is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Using weights are usually just bad for performance when they are nested (See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9430764/why-are-nested-weights-bad-for-performance-alternatives) for example). So in your case you could use them.
Otherwise, you can create an empty view in the middle to help you position the others:

```
<RelativeLayout
    ...
    >
    <View
    androi:id="@+id/separator"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_width="0"
    android:layout_height="0"
    >
    <fragment
    android:layout_above="@id/separator"
    ...
    >
    <fragment
    android:layout_below="@id/separator"
    ...
    >
</RelativeLayout>
```