# What is the best way to create this Layout in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have been struggling for hours to get this layout to work.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context=".MainPreviewActivity">

    <fragment
        android:name="com.apps.foo.CleanPreviewFragment"
        android:id="@+id/clean_preview_fragment"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:name="com.apps.foo.pointop.DirtyPreviewFragment"
        android:id="@+id/filters_fragment"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:name="com.apps.foo.pointop.ProcessedPreviewFragment"
        android:id="@+id/processed_preview_fragment"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </fragment>

</LinearLayout>
```

Every fragment is a simple RelativeLayout (all have the same view):

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.apps.<whatever the fragment name is>">
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now I want make it work like this:

- 1) No nested layout_weight
- 2) No Nesting at all (for example nest the    2 first fragments etc
  etc)
- 3) Not using code to do it    programmatically after the view has
  rendered.

In my opinion the cleanest most readable way of doing this, would be to set the orientation of fragment 1 and fragment 2 to horizontal, and fragment 3 to vertical, but it does not work.

I've also checked [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21182702/using-a-relativelayout-to-vertically-split-two-fragments-evenly),
but the guy, uses a `layout_weight` with a RelativeLayout. RelativeLayouts do ignore weights this will not work.

Any help will be appreciated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a dummy view of `0dp` width and height in the center of the layout using a `RelativeLayout`, and position your Fragments accordingly:

```
<RelativeLayout 
  ... >

  <View
    android:id="@+id/center_anchor"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

  <fragment
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/center_anchor"
    android:layout_above="@id/center_anchor"
    ... />

  <fragment
    android:toLeftOf="@id/center_anchor"
    android:layout_below="@id/center_anchor"
    ... />

  <fragment
    android:toRightOf="@id/center_anchor"
    ... />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: yes but like I mentioned it uses "android:layout_weight="1"" in a relative_layout. Isn't that against the rules? RelativeLayouts ignore weights right? So why is it even working for that guy?

Comment: The `RelativeLayout` has a `LinearLayout` as a parent, so `layout_weight` will work. It's the parent view that acts upon the weight, and `LinearLayout` does support it.

Comment: Please have a look here, http://stackoverflow.com/a/14009266/990194 . Also another question, does it matter what my fragments layouts are?

Comment: `RelativeLayout` does not pay attention to `android:layout_weight` attributes _of its children_. `LinearLayout` does, and in this case `RelativeLayout` is a child of `LinearLayout`.

Comment: @TrtTrt, some attr are applied to the view, others are applied to his parent. In case, putting layout_weight will only work if its parent is a LinearLayout, otherwise it won't work. LinearLayout will see if its children have a weight attr to make any size calculations, you can safely apply weight attr to any kind of view, if its view is inside a LinearLayout than you are using it correctly.