# Position four relative layouts equally on screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I'm trying to position four `RelativeLayouts` on the screen equally as shown on the image below. I just can't seem to get anywhere. Each one will contain a text label and a button centred in their quadrant. I've tried placing the four inside `RelativeLayout` with the `alignComponent` values set appropriately and `alignParent` values set to Left/Right and Top/Bottom. I've also tried with just the `alignComponent` set and just `alignParent` set but to no avail.

It should look like this,

[image]

Comment: you should set weight for each layout...

Comment: you can use `LinearLayout` and its weight property... for that...

Comment: You can easily done it using LinearLayout or tableLayout

Comment: use first layout on default place (left top ), second will be in right of first, third will be down of first and fourth will be down of first and right of third.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you want to use `RelativeLayout`, the easiest way is to use vertical and horizontal *struts* (which are invisible) and use those as anchors for your four `RelativeLayout`s children. This approach is definitely more efficient than nested `LinearLayout`s with weights. You should probably read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9430764/why-are-nested-weights-bad-for-performance-alternatives) before nesting `LinearLayout`s with weights.

A snippet from the above link:

> Layout weights require a widget to be measured twice. When a LinearLayout with non-zero weights is nested inside another LinearLayout with non-zero weights, then the number of measurements increase exponentially.

So for using `RelativeLayout`s with *struts*, your XML could be like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

    <View
        android:id="@+id/horizontalStrut"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/verticalStrut"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/horizontalStrut"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/verticalStrut"
        android:background="@color/red" >
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/horizontalStrut"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/verticalStrut"
        android:background="@color/black" >
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/horizontalStrut"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/verticalStrut"
        android:background="@color/blue" >
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/horizontalStrut"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/verticalStrut"
        android:background="@color/green" >
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try This Layout.. It Could Help You...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/black" >

            <!-- put your stuff here -->
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/red" >

            <!-- put your stuff here -->
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/white" >

            <!-- put your stuff here -->

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/green" >

            <!-- put your stuff here -->

        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Sample Output..

[image]

Comment: @Manish Thnk you Buddy.. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#0B6121"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:background="#DF013A">
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:background="#0080FF">
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#A901DB"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]You can easily done it using LinearLayout or tableLayout, 
SAmple shows using LinearLayout

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="#FF0000" >
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="#331323" >
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="#662200" >
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="#FF8800" >
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use LinearLayout then set android:weightSum for your parent layout then you can set now your  layout_weight for your quadrants.Like this..

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:weightSum = "2"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/black" >
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/red" >
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/white" >
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/green" >
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```