# Nested layout_weight bad for performance: Why do I get Lint warning when I set layout_width value to 0dp?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout, android-layout-weight

I want a `SearchView` at the top of an `Activity`'s layout, and then below that I need to add two `fragment`s aligned horizontally next to each other, such that the right one take double the horizontal space than the left one.

So what I mean is:

The `ViewGroup` containing both the fragments should take up all the remaining space after the `SearchView` is drawn. So I gave it a `layout_weight` of `1`.
Then I added a `LinearLayout` with two `FrameLayout`s for the fragmnets, and gave the left one a `Layout_weight` of `1`, and the right one the value of `2`.

*But I get the Lint warning that nested weights are bad for performance.*

I read about it on SO and [found this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9430764/why-are-nested-weights-bad-for-performance-alternatives):

> Layout weights require a widget to be measured twice.

This [basic tutorial on the developer training here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html) says this thing this way:

> To improve the layout efficiency when you specify the weight, you
>   should change the width of the EditText to be zero (0dp). Setting the
>   width to zero improves layout performance because using "wrap_content"
>   as the width requires the system to calculate a width that is
>   ultimately irrelevant because the weight value requires another width
>   calculation to fill the remaining space.

But since in my layout I am setting the `layout_width="0dp"` when the parent `LinearLayout`'s `orientation` is `vertical`, and `layout_height="0dp"` when the parent `LinearLayout`'s `orientation` is `horizontal`. Why am I still getting the Lint warning?

What can I do about this? Because `RelativeLayout` can't specify how much of the "remaining space" is an element going to take (specified by [layout_weight](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_weight#lattrs), which does not seem to be included in [RelativeLayout.LayoutParams](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html)).

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    android:orientation="vertical"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

    <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
        android:id="@+id/searchActivity_searchView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" >
        <FrameLayout 
            android:id="@+id/searchActivity_frameLayout"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" /><!-- Nested weights are bad for performance Lint Warning -->

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/searchActivity_frameLayout1"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a warning, in this case you should be OK, it's more to keep you from abusing a lot of nested weights and bogging down your app. The other option is to get the screen size at run time and set the width of the Frame Layouts manually.