# Align Numbers with RatingBar - Android

Tags: android, android-studio, ratingbar

I am using a RatingBar in my app and assigning Numbers for Stars for the ease of user but alignment of these Numbers change whenever the device is changed. Although i've used different layouts for different screens but still on some mobile it is not formatting well.

> What i want

[image]

> what's showing on some mobiles

[image]

Comment: Which layout do you use for it grid or linear ?

Comment: i am using linear layout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use constraint layout as a parent and fit a linear layout. That should work fine.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="38dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="192dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/ratingBar"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/ratingBar"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/ratingBar">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:text="1"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView15"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:text="2"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView17"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:text="3"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView18"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:text="4"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView19"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:text="5"
            android:textAlignment="center" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: is this constraint layout necessary? what if i use Linear instead of it?

Comment: I highly recommend `ConstraintLayout`, because it is much more flexible.

Comment: check my edited answer. how can i add the other views?

Comment: I think this solves the main problem, the rest is really just drag and drop. If you are confused with constraint layout try a tutorial and then come back with new questions.

Comment: we don't need to have (layout_editor_absoluteX & layout_editor_absoluteY ). it's better to use start/end/top/bottom of constraint layout. but it's a good sample. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use below type of dynamically changin layout. I added example below. You can add your elements for relevent columns. It will change according to device

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/tempo_activity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:weightSum="2">

             <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_weight="1">

                    <!-- first row -->

                      <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:weightSum="7">

                          <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:orientation="horizontal"
                            android:layout_weight="5">

                             <!-- first column (name) -->

                           </LinearLayout>

                          <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:orientation="horizontal"
                            android:layout_weight="2"
                            android:weightSum="5">

                             <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:orientation="horizontal"
                                android:layout_weight="4">

                                 <!-- second column (name) -->

                             </LinearLayout>

                              <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:orientation="horizontal"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:weightSum="4">


                                  <LinearLayout
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                                    android:layout_weight="3">

                                     <!-- third column (name) -->

                                 </LinearLayout>

                                 <LinearLayout
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                                    android:layout_weight="1"
                                    android:weightSum="3">

                                       <LinearLayout
                                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                            android:orientation="horizontal"
                                            android:layout_weight="2">

                                             <!-- fourth column (name) -->

                                       </LinearLayout>

                                        <LinearLayout
                                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                            android:orientation="horizontal"
                                            android:layout_weight="1"
                                            android:weightSum="2">

                                                   <LinearLayout
                                                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                                                        android:layout_weight="1">

                                                         <!-- fifth column (name) -->

                                                   </LinearLayout>
                                                    <LinearLayout
                                                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                                                        android:layout_weight="1">

                                                         <!-- sixth column (name) -->

                                                   </LinearLayout>


                                       </LinearLayout>



                                 </LinearLayout>


                             </LinearLayout>


                           </LinearLayout>

                     </LinearLayout>


             </LinearLayout>

             <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_weight="1">

                    <!-- second row -->

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:weightSum="7">

                          <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:orientation="horizontal"
                            android:layout_weight="5">

                             <!-- first column (name) -->

                           </LinearLayout>

                          <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:orientation="horizontal"
                            android:layout_weight="2"
                            android:weightSum="5">

                             <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:orientation="horizontal"
                                android:layout_weight="4">

                                 <!-- second column (name) -->

                             </LinearLayout>

                              <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:orientation="horizontal"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:weightSum="4">


                                  <LinearLayout
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                                    android:layout_weight="3">

                                     <!-- third column (name) -->

                                 </LinearLayout>

                                 <LinearLayout
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                                    android:layout_weight="1"
                                    android:weightSum="3">

                                       <LinearLayout
                                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                            android:orientation="horizontal"
                                            android:layout_weight="2">

                                             <!-- fourth column (name) -->

                                       </LinearLayout>

                                        <LinearLayout
                                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                            android:orientation="horizontal"
                                            android:layout_weight="1"
                                            android:weightSum="2">

                                                   <LinearLayout
                                                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                                                        android:layout_weight="1">

                                                         <!-- fifth column (name) -->

                                                   </LinearLayout>
                                                    <LinearLayout
                                                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                                                        android:layout_weight="1">

                                                         <!-- sixth column (name) -->

                                                   </LinearLayout>


                                       </LinearLayout>



                                 </LinearLayout>


                             </LinearLayout>


                           </LinearLayout>

                     </LinearLayout>

             </LinearLayout>




   </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: The nesting on this is horrible

Comment: @leonardkraemer this will dynamically adjust layout what u want. What do you suggest grid layout ?  Grid layout cannot have much flexibility like this. But in this example his can use it as well

Comment: Your layout does not even include a rating bar. Also nested `LinearLayouts` especially with weight suns are slow and should be avoided. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9430764/why-are-nested-weights-bad-for-performance-alternatives

Comment: this code is very complicated bro. can't it be much simpler?