# TableLayout vs ConstraintLayout Performance

Tags: android, performance, android-constraintlayout, android-tablelayout

I couldn't find anything comparing the performance of the two. Would imitating a TableLayout with a ConstraintLayout perform better than a TableLayout on its own?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `TableLayout` and `TableRow` both extend from `LinearLayout`, comparing them to a `ConstraintLayout` will be the same as comparing two nested `LinearLayout` with one `ConstraintLayout`.

The [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/rendering/optimizing-view-hierarchies) and [this Android developers article](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/08/understanding-performance-benefits-of.html) describes the benefits of `ConstraintLayout` over other `ViewGroup` types.

`ConstraintLayout` will outperform nested `LinearLayout` specially if they [have defined weights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9430764/why-are-nested-weights-bad-for-performance-alternatives), as it would be common in `TableLayout`.

> Layout weights require a widget to be measured twice. When a
>   LinearLayout with non-zero weights is nested inside another
>   LinearLayout with non-zero weights, then the number of measurements
>   increase exponentially.