# Layout has too many views

Tags: android, performance, android-cardview, android-gridlayout

I am currently trying to create cash register based app with 5x5 grid to display all the menu.
I used GridLayout with CardView to display them. 1 CardView with linearLayout+ Imageview + TextView resulted in total 4 views, so 5x5 cardview made my xml end up with 100 views...

I tried to use include tags for the linearlayout+ imageview+textview inside the cardview, which brought the views down to  50 views only. 
But the problem now is: I'd like to change the text and image `src` inside the include tags, otherwise I cant display all the menu images. Is this even possible?

Any suggestion for my problems?

```
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">
            <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:weightSum="100"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                >
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="70"
                    android:src="@drawable/noimage"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/logo" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textColor="#A9A9A9"
                    android:layout_weight="30"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
                    android:text="@string/logo"/>
            </LinearLayout>


        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">
            <include layout="@layout/menu_cardview"/>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: See my answer for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61477058/how-to-set-a-layout-width-percentage-of-one-third-on-constraintlayout/61478206#61478206

Comment: You can use Recyclerview with GridLayoutManager for this type of view. To create a single item you can also use Constraint Layout instead of nested LinearLayouts.

Comment: linked answer is a really bad answer, and also not applicable for this situation.

Comment: @RehanSarwar that might actually works for me, i will try it for now

Answer (score 0):

I think it's currently not possible but what you can do to reduce/optimize your xml code is 
First Option:

use only TextViews in GridLayout and for images above them don't use separate ImageViews use this in TextViews `android:drawabkeTop="drawable/image`

Second Option :

Second option is which you can also use along with first option. Use Styles to style your layout 
Example :

```
 <style name="gridImageStyle">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:src">@drwable/image</item>
</style>

<style name="gridTextStyle">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">20sp</item>
</style>
```

and use it in your TextView and ImageView like this

```
              <TextView
                    style="@style/gridTextStyle"
                    android:text="EnterTextHere"/>

              <ImageView
                    style="@style/gridImageStyle"
                    android:src="Enter Image Source here"/>
```

But, I would recommend to you to use `android:drawableTop:"ImageSource"` in TextView instead of ImageView